How can I change the horizontal spacing while using enumerate and multicols environment?
I want to change the spacing of the text  'rights' from orange to purple and also that of the line from blue to red.

The code I've used is given below :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,wide,label=$\arabic*$)]
\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}
\item Begin all powerful
\item A person who eats too much.
\item A place where a person lives permanently.
\item One who defends his country`s freedom or rights.      
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,wide,label= ,itemsep=10pt]
\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}       
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


welcome to TeX.SE!

What is your end goal here? Having numbered items on the left and commensurate rules on the right?

Off-topic: left=15mm,right=15mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm may be expressed more compactly as hmargin=15mm,vmargin=25mm.

@Werner I want to change the alignment of the text 'rights' from its current position that is orange to that of the alignment of other text indicated in purple colour.

@Mico Oh is it ! Thanks, I've only started using LaTeX for a couple of days and learned it via videos so I'm not really well versed in these.

@Mensch Oh thank you...

My main recommendation is that you change the option wide to left=0pt in the first or "outer" enumerate environment.
Some additional housekeeping chores: (a) Unless your text-font and math-font numerals are quite different, you should simplify label=$\arabic*$) to label=\arabic*). (b) For the sake of compactness, I'd delete (or comment out) both \setlength{\itemsep}{10pt} directives and specify itemsep=10pt as an option of the enumerate environments. (c) Since no enumeration is going on in the "inner" enumerate environment, I'd simplify it to an itemize environment. (d) I can't see a good reason for nesting the second enumerate (or itemize) environment inside the first enumerate environment.

Aside: I have no idea what you have planned for the \rule{5cm}{0.75pt} directives in the second column. If your (eventual) goal is to make the lines as wide as possible, I suggest you (a) change the "inner" instance of wide to left=0pt as well and (b) replace all four instances of \rule{5cm}{0.75pt} with \rule{\linewidth}{0.75pt}.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=15mm,vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, itemsep=10pt, left=0pt, label=\arabic*)]
%\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}
\item Begin all powerful
\item A person who eats too much.
\item A place where a person lives permanently.
\item One who defends his country`s freedom or rights.
\end{enumerate} 
      
\begin{itemize}[nosep, itemsep=10pt, wide, label=]
%\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{5cm}{0.75pt}
\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's follow-up comments, regarding how to modify the appearance of the lines in the right-hand column. If I understand the OP's objectives correctly, the lines should start further to the right, while not extending all the way to the right-hand margin. If this understanding is correct, I suggest (a) setting the option left=1cm (or whatever is deemed necessary) instead of either wide or left=0pt and (b) choosing a slightly larger for value of the first argument of \rule. E.g., instead of 5cm, choose either 6cm or 7cm. (Choosing \linewidth would make the lines extend to the right-hand margin.)
The following code also illustrates which measures have to be taken in order to keep the material in the two columns aligned.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=15mm,vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}[nosep, itemsep=10pt, left=0pt, label=\arabic*)]
\item Begin all powerful.
\item A person who eats too much.
\item One who defends his country's freedom or rights.
\item A place where a person lives permanently.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}[nosep, itemsep=10pt, left=1cm, label=]
\item  \rule{7cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{7cm}{0.75pt}
\item  \rule{7cm}{0.75pt} \newline\phantom{abc}
\item  \rule{7cm}{0.75pt}
\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}


Oh Thank you so much  and also I wanted to ask one more thing, Can I change the spacing between the text and that of lines as per my requirements ?

@AswinK.S - Are you talking about the vertical or the horizontal spacing?

The horizontal space between them. I want the lines to move a bit from the text but not all the way up to the margin.

@AswinK.S - Please try to be a bit more specific that "move a bit from the text but not all the way". By the way, which margin are considering? (Sorry, but my ability to read minds has always been, and sadly always will be, utterly worthless.)

Well I just wanted to know that when we are using multicols, could we have the option to change the horizontal spacing. Like in this cause  if I'm not happy with this horizontal spacing, how could I change it? And sorry for my vague explanation, I've only started using LaTeX like 3 days ago so that's why I'm not really able to explain the problem correctly.

@AswinK.S - Please see the addendum I posted.

Oh thank you so much, you gave me the exact solution that I was looking for ✨

One last thing , Is there any way of getting the text "rights" on the same line with the text "One who defends his country's freedom or" ? Sorry for asking too many questions, this is my school work and I need it to look really professional.

@AswinK.S - For the entry in question, just place phantom{abc}\newline before \rule{7cm}{0.75pt}.
